# How to check current TCP Congestion Window on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

**Does anyone know how to check the current value of `initcwnd`?** (particularly on Debian [Squeeze])

I've searched, but can't find a definitive answer to this.  I haven't changed it, but may want to depending on it's current setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the source code of your running kernel and inspect `include/net/tcp.h`. There you will find:

```
/* TCP initial congestion window */
#define TCP_INIT_CWND 10
```

This being the default value, and rarely changed even in userland, it isn't otherwise exposed.

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll try to get the source, although this is a custom build for a Xen VPS.  A pity it's not exposed to the users.  Thanks for providing a definitive answer though.

Comment: Ah, indeed it was 10 :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [CDN planet](http://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/tune-tcp-initcwnd-for-optimum-performance/#change-initcwnd), you would find it by typing

```
ip route show
```

Maybe this assumes that you have changed it yourself first.

Comment: Yes, that only shows the value if you have changed it yourself unfortunately.  I'm looking for a way of finding the current value regardless of whether or not it was changed.

Comment: According to [kernel newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_39#head-c2acd2f0463943210471a42bf6f5b469a6999e7b) it is set to 10 per default, if you use kernel 2.6.39 or later.

Comment: Thanks.  Still would like to be able to verify though.